# Sesión en servidor se cambia de usuario en Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

En una aplicación que tengo en Laravle 5.4 que tiene varios usuarios logueados al mismo tiempo, se les cambia de usuario.
Por ejemplo yo me logueo y después de un momento, al actualizar la página, ya estoy conectado como otro usuario.
Ya intenté en cambiar el driver para el manejo de la sesión de **file** a **cookie** y también intenté con **database**
En la aplicación estoy guardando datos con ajax, no se si esto afecte la sesión.
Me enteré de la situación porque los usuarios de la aplicación me reportaron que se les cambiaba de usuario, el nombre del usuario logueado siempre está visible en una esquina.
No he podido detectar si ocurre con una acción específica, simplemente refrescando la vista de mi perfil de un momento a otro pasa a ser otro usuario el que está logueado en mi máquina.
Estoy usando el sistema de autenticación de laravel por defecto.
Este es mi archivo .env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:d/eIgceeE8C5srGrE0K9Ktj6wfaANvhcQrTuDTY44rc=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL='url del sitio'

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE='base de datos'
DB_USERNAME='usuario'
DB_PASSWORD='contraseña'

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Y este my archivo config/session.php

```
return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    'encrypt' => false,

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    'connection' => null,

    'table' => 'sessions',

    'store' => null,

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

    'path' => '/',

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    'http_only' => true,

];
```

En el controlador obtengo los datos del usuario y los envío a la vista:

```
$user = Auth::user();

// obtengo mas datos

return view('vista.index', ['user' => $user, 'datos' => $datos]);
```

Y en la vista simplemente muestro los datos con:

```
<h3 class="nombre">{{ $user->name }}</h3>
```

Ahora, después de cargar la vista cargo varios inputs, 64 en total, cada vez que cambio el valor de uno de los input muestro un botón para guardar el valor del input, y este guardado lo hago con ajax:

```
$('.guardar').click(function(){

var campo = $(this).attr('name');

var url = $('input[name=urlsave]').val();

$.post(
url, 
{
  _token: $('input[name=_token]').val(),
}, 
function(data){
  if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
    $('.label'+ campo).html(data.success).addTempClass( 'exito', 3000 );
    $('div.' + campo).addClass('ok');
  }else{
    $('label.' + campo).html(data.error[0]).addTempClass( 'error', 3000 );
    $('div.' + campo).addClass('error');
  }
}
);
});
```

Comment: Como? muestra algo de codigo, asi como lo planteas no se te podra ayudar, muestra la parte de codigo en donde se  cambia de usuaio. o como te diste cuenta de eso?

Comment: Una ultima cosilla. Cuando dices : "el nombre del usuario logueado siempre está visible en una esquina", podrías mostrar también como lo estas haciendo?. puede que ese sea el problema.

Comment: pues todo parece ir bien, lo lamento pero no encuentro la razon de tu error.

Comment: Por casualidad tus usuarios acceden a la aplicacion mediante un proxy!?o tu aplicacion corre en una LAN!? Si es el primer caso, pudiera ser que el proxy está almacenando en caché los resultados de las peticiones a tu aplicacion y le esta entregando a los usuarios paginas guardadas. Posiblemente veas resultados del primer usuario autenticado.

Comment: Está en un servidor compartido, al parecer es un problema de laravel cuando hay varios requests, se pierde el session auth. Estoy ensayando algo, bloqueo de sesion https://github.com/rairlie/laravel-locking-session y si funciona lo publico como respuesta

Comment: me gustaria saber si pudiste resolver el problema ya que tambien me he topado con esto

Comment: A la final no pudimos solucionar el problema, así que nos cambiamos de hosting

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema, con laravel 5.3... tu problema fue de hosting?

Comment: Si, cuando cambiamos de hosting no tuvimos más problemas